# session variable not being stored from dropdown menu in php

Tags: php, mysql, session, drop-down-menu, session-variables

I have looked up many different ways of storing session variables and cant seem to find why my session variable is not being stored from my dropdown menu. here is my code for campaign_select.php which then goes to store_select.php upon the push of the submit button.

```
    <?php
    session_start ();
    $host="localhost"; // Host name 
    $username="sxx2"; // Mysql username 
    $password="xxxxx!"; // Mysql password 
    $db_name="sxxxxx"; // Database name 
    $tbl_name="campaign"; // Table name 

    // Connect to server and select databse.
    mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
    mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

    $query = "SELECT campaignname FROM campaign";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
    $dd .= "<option value='{$row['campaignID']}'>{$row['campaignname']}</option>";
    } 
    if ($_POST['Submit']) 
    {

    if(isset($_POST['campaignname']))
    {   
    $_SESSION['campaign']=$_POST['campaignName'];
    }
    } 
    $_SESSION['test']="bye";
    ?>

    <form action="store_select.php" method="post">
    <select name="campaignName" id="campaignname"><? echo $dd; ?></select>
<input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

and here is store_select.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="sxxxx2"; // Mysql username 
$password="Wxxxx1!"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="xxxx2"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="users"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$campaign=$_SESSION['campaign'];
echo $_SESSION['campaign'];
echo $_SESSION['test'];

$query = "SELECT storename FROM stores WHERE campaignname='$campaign'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());


while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $dd .= "<option value='{$row['storeID']}'>{$row['storename']}</option>";
} 
?>
<form action="" method="post">
<select name="stores"><? echo $dd; ?></select>
</form>
```

Comment: Daryl, if we helped you, it would be nice if you would accept one of the answers, this will help future visitors. If you still need help, just say so, no problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are executing your script in the wrong order. This is what you are doing:

- Script 1: Construct form
- Script 1: Put form result ($_POST) into session:

```
    if ($_POST['Submit']) {
        if(isset($_POST['campaignname']))
        {   
            $_SESSION['campaign']=$_POST['campaignName'];
        }
    }
```

`$_POST` is empty at this point. Only when the user clicks "submit" and is taken to your second script, will `$_POST` be filled with your values. You can skip the check for `$_POST['Submit']`, this is not needed.

- Script 1: Send form result to script 2
- Script 2: Display stuff from $_SESSION. It will already display 'test', but with the change above, now you will get the expected output. Always remember that $_POST gets filled  by the user posting (submitting) a form. No submission, no values.

BTW, you shouldn't use the value you received from $_POST in another query without checking for malicious input - you saw how easy it is to manipulate the data. This is called SQL injection.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean in Step 3??

Comment: Unable to put form first as populating drop down requires declaration first??

Comment: You are creating your dropdown menu just fine. You just need to put the block I highlighted above into your second script.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
<form action="store_select.php" method="post">
```

with

```
<form action="" method="post">
```

and

```
if(isset($_POST['campaignname']))
```

with

```
if(isset($_POST['campaignName']))
```

Comment: Same problem occurred, Drop down menu in "store_select.php" still not populated??

Comment: print this query and check it by running it directly on mysql console whether it really returns anything $query = "SELECT storename FROM stores WHERE campaignname='$campaign'";

Comment: SQL statement is correct since if $campaign is hardcoded as a value from the database its populates correctly. Problem is $campaign is not being assigned to session variable in campaign_select.php